# nodejs send http, then how to send callback data to index.ejs

Tags: node.js, http

first,nodejs code like this

```
var express = require('express');
var http =  require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');  
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
exports.index = function(req, res){
    var opt = {  
        method: "POST",  
        host: "localhost",  
        port: 8080,  
        path: "/mongoresume/resumeList.json" 
    };  

    var req = http.request(opt, function (serverFeedback) {  
      if (serverFeedback.statusCode == 200) {  
            var body = "";  
            serverFeedback.on('data', function (data) { body += data; console.log(data);})  
                          .on('end', function () { res.render("index",body);/*res.send(200, body); */});  
        }  
        else {  
            res.send(500, "error");  
        }  
    });  

    req.on('error', function (e) {  
        console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);  
    });  

  //  req.write(data + "\n");  
    req.end();

};
```

when I use normal code like `res.send(200, body);`,it can receive data,but i want send data to index.ejs,so when I modify code like `res.render("index",body);`, it threw error

[image]

So what's the error means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second parameter to the res.render function should be an object. You are providing a string (the body variable). Express tries to add a property to a string variable, which of course fails and causes your error message. Look up the [documentation about res.render()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render).

Answer (score 0):

The parameter should be an object and not as such body. Try like this

```
res.render('index',result:JSON.parse(body)['object name']);
```